# Как перебрать и вывести многомерный массив на php?

Tags: php, массивы

Помогите перебрать и вывести массив на PHP

Имеется массив:

```
    Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Первый
            [1] => Впервые мы смогли
            [2] => Перваши
        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-11-05 12:51:02
            [1] => 2020-11-05 15:26:09
            [2] => 2020-11-03 15:27:26
        )

    [rating] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1000
            [1] => 1212
            [2] => 111111
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1000 MB
            [1] => 441 GB
            [2] => 132 mb
        )

    [views] => Array
        (
            [0] => 56252
            [1] => 1111
            [2] => 1231
        )
)
```

Нужно, чтобы строчка из массива формировалась по номеру в массиве.
Пытаюсь вывести в строчку, чтобы получилось так:

> Строка первая - id = 1 | title = Первый | date = 2020-11-05
> 12:51:02 | rating  = 1000
>  Строка вторая - id = 1 | title  =
> Первый | date = 2020-11-05 12:51:02 | rating  = 1212
>  ......
>  N
> неизвестно, сколько будет строк в массиве.
> Понял, что нужно через фореч выводить, но выводится по порядку, а нужно как в примере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное как то так

```
$data_raw = ['id' => [1, 2, 3], 
             'title' => ['Первый','Впервые мы смогли','Перваши'], 
             'date' => ['2020-11-05 12:51:02','2020-11-05 15:26:09','2020-11-03 15:27:26'],
             'rating' => [1000, 1212, 111111], 'size' => ['1000 MB','441 GB','132 mb'],
             'views' => [56252, 1111, 1231]];
$data = [];
foreach($data_raw AS $first_key => $array) {
    foreach($array AS $key => $value)
        $data[$key][$first_key] = $value;
}

var_export($data);

// результат
array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 1, 'title' => 'Первый', 'date' => '2020-11-05 12:51:02', 'rating' => 1000, 'size' => '1000 MB', 'views' => 56252, ), 1 => array ( 'id' => 2, 'title' => 'Впервые мы смогли', 'date' => '2020-11-05 15:26:09', 'rating' => 1212, 'size' => '441 GB', 'views' => 1111, ), 2 => array ( 'id' => 3, 'title' => 'Перваши', 'date' => '2020-11-03 15:27:26', 'rating' => 111111, 'size' => '132 mb', 'views' => 1231, ), )
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_map`+`array_combine`, создаёт полную копию в памяти ещё до использования, зато oneliner.

```
$data = [
    'id'     => [1, 2, 3], 
    'title'  => ['Первый', 'Впервые мы смогли', 'Перваши'], 
    'date'   => ['2020-11-05 12:51:02', '2020-11-05 15:26:09', '2020-11-03 15:27:26'],
    'rating' => [1000, 1212, 111111],
    'size'   => ['1000 MB', '441 GB', '132 mb'],
    'views'  => [56252, 1111, 1231]
];


$rows = array_map(
    fn(...$vals) => array_combine(array_keys($data), $vals),  
    ...array_values($data));
    
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo json_encode($row, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), PHP_EOL;
}
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/vqQDK)

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrs=array(
    "id" => array(
            "0" => "1",
            "1" => "2",
            "2" => "3"
        ),

    "title" => array(
            "0" => "Первый",
            "1" => "Впервые мы смогли",
            "2" => "Перваши"
        ),

    "date" => array
        (
            "0" => "2020-11-05 12:51:02",
            "1" => "2020-11-05 15:26:09",
            "2" => "2020-11-03 15:27:26"
        ),

    "rating" => array
        (
            "0" => "1000",
            "1" => "1212",
            "2" => "111111"
        ),

    "size" => array
        (
            "0" => "1000 MB",
            "1" => "441 GB",
            "2" => "132 mb"
        ),

    "views" => array
        (
            "0" => "56252",
            "1" => "1111",
            "2" => "1231"
        )
);



for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) { 
    # code...

print_r("ID - ".$arrs["id"][$i]."|Title - ".$arrs["title"][$i]."|date - ".$arrs["date"][$i]."|rating - ".$arrs["rating"][$i]."|size - ".$arrs["size"][$i]."|views - ".$arrs["views"][$i]);
echo "<br>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Итератор с yield, экономнее по памяти, так как собирает необходимые данные на каждой итерации.

```
function iterate_combined(array $data) {
    if (!$data) {
      return [];
    }
    $fields = array_keys($data);
    $n = count(reset($data));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
        $row = [];
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $row[$field] = $data[$field][$i];
        }
        yield $row;
    }
}

$data = [
    'id'     => [1, 2, 3], 
    'title'  => ['Первый', 'Впервые мы смогли', 'Перваши'], 
    'date'   => ['2020-11-05 12:51:02', '2020-11-05 15:26:09', '2020-11-03 15:27:26'],
    'rating' => [1000, 1212, 111111],
    'size'   => ['1000 MB', '441 GB', '132 mb'],
    'views'  => [56252, 1111, 1231]
];

foreach (iterate_combined($data) as $row) {
    echo json_encode($row, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), PHP_EOL;
}
```

> ```
> {"id":1,"title":"Первый","date":"2020-11-05 12:51:02","rating":1000,"size":"1000 MB","views":56252}
> {"id":2,"title":"Впервые мы смогли","date":"2020-11-05 15:26:09","rating":1212,"size":"441 GB","views":1111}
> {"id":3,"title":"Перваши","date":"2020-11-03 15:27:26","rating":111111,"size":"132 mb","views":1231}
> ```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/X9ONY)

Comment: `array_map(null, ...$data)` +`array_combine` можно было приплести

Comment: Хм, не вижу как :) `...$data` со строковыми ключами резольвится в пустое множество.

Comment: Впрочем, я уже приплёл нечто подобное в соседнем ответе)